# Randomly reorder pages in PDF document

Tags: pdf, script, random-number-generator

I'm looking for a series of commands to randomize the order of pages in an existing PDF document.

Comment: See also [How can I shuffle pages from a PDF file in a random order?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209637/80216)  (on Unix&Linux)

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, there's a nice python library pyPDF which can be used in the following script to randomize the order of pages in a PDF document.

The script below, call it `mixpdf`, creates a copy of an input PDF file with randomly reordered pages when called by the statement `mixpdf myinputfile.pdf`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import random

from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

# read input pdf and instantiate output pdf
output = PdfFileWriter()
input1 = PdfFileReader(file(sys.argv[1],"rb"))

# construct and shuffle page number list
pages = list(range(input1.getNumPages()))
random.shuffle(pages)

# display new sequence
print 'Reordering pages according to sequence:'
print pages

# add the new sequence of pages to output pdf
for page in pages:
    output.addPage(input1.getPage(page))

# write the output pdf to file
outputStream = file(sys.argv[1]+'-mixed.pdf','wb')
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, I advice to use `qpdf` and `shuf` in a *bash script*.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

INPUT="${1}"
OUTPUT=$(basename "${INPUT}" .pdf)-rand.pdf
NPAGES=$(qpdf --show-npages "${INPUT}")
RANDOM_PERMUTATION=$(shuf -i 1-${NPAGES} | xargs | tr ' ' ',')

qpdf --empty --pages "${INPUT}" ${RANDOM_PERMUTATION} -- "${OUTPUT}"
```